# Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib On Mac

Tags: bash, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Let me make it clear first,  none of available answers worked for me!

I am using Laravel Valet. And iTerm2 with .zsh. When i run php artisan it gives me following error:

[image]

I tried following fixes but nothing worked form me.

```
 brew remove openssl
 brew install openssl
```

This did not fixed my problem. Then i tried to do another one

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

By doing this it works for that opened tab only but on left side it shows something like this:

`\h:\W \u$`

[image]

So so tried to do this:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
    source ~/.zshrc
```

I thought it would work but it also did not work. :)

I have tried restarting iTerm also.

I also checked Library is exist in my `usr/local/opt/openssl`

So what would be the reason for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `bash` and `zsh` are two different shells. `.bash_profile` is no longer relevant if you use `zsh`. Further, `PATH` isn't involved in finding libraries.